# I want to select the main div

Tags: javascript, jquery

My up and down arrows are in a div that is a couple of divs down and is also an image. I need to move the div with the class name handle, when I click the arrows. If I was to put handle in the selector the code works fine, but I don't want to click the handle I want to be able to click the images but I can't seem to get the selector to go high enough.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.moveUp2').click(function(){
        var diveItem = $(this).parent();
        if (diveItem.prev().is('div'))
        {
            diveItem.insertBefore(diveItem.prev())
        }
    });

    $('.moveDown2').click(function(){
        var diveItem = $(this).parent();
        if (diveItem.next().is('div'))
        {
            diveItem.insertAfter(diveItem.next())
        }
    }) 
});
</script>




    <div style="background-color: #dceaf4;" class="handle">
        <div style="float:left;"><b class="order_interaction" id="interactionOrder">{{order}}.</b>&#160;</div>
        <div style="float:left;"><b id="interactionType">{{type}}</b></div>
        <div style="width:100%; text-align:right;">
            <div style="text-align:right;">

                <a href="#" class="interactionComments">
                    <img style="cursor:pointer;" title="Comments" src="img/messages.png"/>
                </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                {{#if showControls}}
                    <a class="moveUp_interaction">
                        <img style="cursor:pointer;" src="img/arrow_up_blue.png" class="moveup2" title="Move Up">
                    </a>

                    <a class="moveDown_interaction">
                        <img style="cursor:pointer;" src="img/arrow_down_blue.png" class="movedown2" title="Move down">
                    </a>

                    <a class="del_interaction">
                        <img style="cursor:pointer;" src="img/delete.png" class="delete" title="Delete">
                    </a>
                {{/if}}

            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your code isn't working because the classnames being used do not match. The element's are using classes `moveup2` and `movedown2` and the click event is for class `moveUp2` and `moveDown2`.

Comment: that doesnt seem to be the answer either.

Comment: Well you need to make some corrections; however, what exactly are you trying to do? what element do you want to select and what do you want to happen? Do you want to select the `.handle` div? Then what are you "inserting"? Are you changing the order of the icons?

Comment: I do want to select the handle div. When I press the arrow image, the handle div will sort with the other divs. This works if I have .handle as my selector and I click anywhere in the div, but i want it to only sort when i press the arrow images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem on my own and thought i would share the answer.

```
$('.moveUp2').click(function(){
    var diveItem = $(this).parents('div:eq(3)');
    if (diveItem.prev().is('div'))
    {
        diveItem.insertBefore(diveItem.prev())
        }
});

$('.moveDown2').click(function(){
    var diveItem = $(this).parents('div:eq(3)');
    if (diveItem.next().is('div'))
    {
        diveItem.insertAfter(diveItem.next())
        }
});
```